# Member Variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables, concatenation, member

I'm trying to create a console input program in which a user can add HTML to a file.

So if you pressed B(for bold)
and then your input was "test"
It would put "test" into the file.

The problem is, there is only one function "SaveToFile" that actually should be saving it to the file, and until that function is called, I'm expected to keep the output queued up somehow to later write onto the file, or to clear instead of putting into the file.

I know java and C# so my thought was to have some type of member variable
and just concatenate the lines:

```
   mOutput += ("<B>"+userinput+"<B/>);
```

Any idea how I would achieve something like this in python?

Comment: (sarcasm alert) You can try searching for ["python member variables"](http://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-python-classes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same way as in the other languages. The differences are:

- In a Python method, you always have to refer to a member variable (generally called instance attributes) by specifying the object it's attached to, even if it's your own instance. This is achieved by Python automatically passing a reference to your instance as the first argument to your method, which is by convention named `self`. So instead of `mOutput` you would probably write `self.output` (no Hungarian  necessary since the `self` makes it obvious that it's a member variable).
- The container you want to use for this is a `list`. You call the list's `append` method to add an item to it. Lists also support `+=` but this expects a sequence, not a single item. Worse, strings are considered sequences of characters, so using `+=` to append a string to a list would append the individual characters of the string as separate items! You could *make* the second argument a sequence by writing e.g. `container += [item_to_add]`, but that forces Python to construct a second list for no good reason.
- Instance attributes must be explicitly initialized at instantiation. If you define the attribute on the class, such as writing `output = []` in the class definition, that attribute is shared among all instances of the class (unless the instances override it by providing an attribute with the same name). Instead, write `self.output = []` in your `__init__` method.
- You can use the `join` method of strings to join a sequence together. The string specified is the delimiter between the joined elements. (This is backward from most languages, but makes sense after a while.)

Putting this all together:

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.output = []   # empty list

    def bold(self, userinput):
        self.output.append("<B>" + userinput + "</B>")        

    def save(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
            # write items separated by line breaks
            outfile.write("\n".join(self.output))
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Incredibly helpful. I understand that your save function is outputting to the file and using creating a new line for each element in the list, but might I ask what the "w" is for?

Comment: "w" means "write mode." The specified file will be created if it doesn't exist; if it does exist, it is emptied. See .e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open or in Python, `help(open)`.